# Limit the Internet bandwidth of Android device

Tags: internet, bandwidth

Is it possible to limit internet speed of Android device

for example

- Nexus 7 only internet speed has 300 kbps / 1mbps
- Nexus 4 only internet speed has 150 kbps / 1mbps

Comment: Do you mean over your WiFi network? Typically you'd configure this on your router. (Yes, I realize this is an old question...)

Answer (score 3):

While not for the faint of heart, how about the Linux command Traffic Control? Check out the [man page](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) for a quick run-down.

You'll need root and the [Android Terminal Emulator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) (or similar). I think [this guide](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/traffic-control.php) will be helpful, especially the script quoted below (although because I'm not rooted I haven't tried it myself). You can either try to run the script [using sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094562/how-to-run-bash-script-in-my-android) or [using BASH](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=537827), or simply type the commands from the script directly in terminal after replacing the variables with your desired values. Let us know how it goes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  tc uses the following units when passed as a parameter.
#  kbps: Kilobytes per second 
#  mbps: Megabytes per second
#  kbit: Kilobits per second
#  mbit: Megabits per second
#  bps: Bytes per second 
#       Amounts of data can be specified in:
#       kb or k: Kilobytes
#       mb or m: Megabytes
#       mbit: Megabits
#       kbit: Kilobits
#  To get the byte figure from bits, divide the number by 8 bit
#

#
# Name of the traffic control command.
TC=/sbin/tc

# The network interface we're planning on limiting bandwidth.
IF=eth0             # Interface

# Download limit (in mega bits)
DNLD=1mbit          # DOWNLOAD Limit

# Upload limit (in mega bits)
UPLD=1mbit          # UPLOAD Limit

# IP address of the machine we are controlling
IP=216.3.128.12     # Host IP

# Filter options for limiting the intended interface.
U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32"

start() {

# We'll use Hierarchical Token Bucket (HTB) to shape bandwidth.
# For detailed configuration options, please consult Linux man
# page.

    $TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD
    $U32 match ip dst $IP/32 flowid 1:1
    $U32 match ip src $IP/32 flowid 1:2

# The first line creates the root qdisc, and the next two lines
# create two child qdisc that are to be used to shape download 
# and upload bandwidth.
#
# The 4th and 5th line creates the filter to match the interface.
# The 'dst' IP address is used to limit download speed, and the 
# 'src' IP address is used to limit upload speed.

}

stop() {

# Stop the bandwidth shaping.
    $TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

# Self-explanatory.
    stop
    sleep 1
    start

}

show() {

# Display status of traffic control status.
    $TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF

}

case "$1" in

  start)

    echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
    start
    echo "done"
    ;;

  stop)

    echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
    stop
    echo "done"
    ;;

  restart)

    echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
    restart
    echo "done"
    ;;

  show)

    echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:"
    show
    echo ""
    ;;

  *)

    pwd=$(pwd)
    echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
    ;;

esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound). It's a system wide download speed shaper/limiter. Few things to note:

- The app requires root access.
- It works by dropping packets using `iptables`. This wastes some traffic - how much depends on the type of traffic (e.g. long running download, web browsing).
- Rate measurement is done by number of packets instead of bytes so the speed limit won't be accurate.
- This only limits TCP traffic (it makes no sense to drop UDP packets).

Note also that I'm the author of this app.

Comment: Any plans to implement upload speed limit and not just download ? Google photos sync is extremely annoying for a shared network.

Comment: Any chance you could lower the required API version? I'm using Android 4.2.1 and cannot use your app...

Comment: A second request for upload limits too?

Answer (score 1):

Well There is no such app at the moment but google is planning to introduce this in the near future.. [Bandwidth Throttling Feature](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/google-android-smartphone-tablet-bandwidth-throttling,news-15109.html)

Comment: No, not data usage, I mean having an internet usage limit in android device

Comment: do you mean usage through the browser? but should not include apps internet usage such as gmail etc.

Comment: All android apps...

Comment: if you use the application above it will limit the internet usage. you can define a limit and once that limit is reached the applications would not be able to access the internet. I think that is what you want. if not, please clarify in detail.

Comment: do you really need an app in the phone? or you may want to use alternate methods as well such methods are without the phone app.

Comment: bandwidth throttling was implemented with Android 13 as `INGRESS_RATE_LIMIT_BYTES_PER_SECOND` - https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/topic:bandwidth-limiting