# Limit download rate in android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, wifi-hotspot, mobile-network, asus-zenfone-5

I have an irritating friend of mine who has evil eye on my unlimited data plan. I have a few time asked him to do his own recharge but he tends not to. It's so irritating when he asks to tether.

Can I limit my download speed to 1 kbps? Or maybe 1/2?

Comment: Well, yes that's something which I also want to know, because there are times when I want other people connected to my device via tethering doesn't get the speed, in other words I do want to limit them !

Answer (score 2):

**FOR NON-ROOTED DEVICES**

*Go to `Settings` > `More` > `Mobile Networks`

*Uncheck **Mobile Data Service Preferred**

**FOR ROOTED DEVICED**
(Copied from Mansour's answer on [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33661/limit-the-internet-bandwidth-of-android-device) )

> Checkout [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound). It's a system wide download speed shaper/limiter. Few things to note:
>
> - The app requires root access.
> - It works by dropping packets using `iptables`. This wastes some traffic - how much depends on the type of traffic (e.g. long running download, web browsing).
> - Rate measurement is done by number of packets instead of bytes so the speed limit won't be accurate.
> - This only limits TCP traffic (it makes no sense to drop UDP packets).
>
> Note also that I'm the author of this app.

Comment: Well, I think this would put an hold to the data limit not the data transfer limit. I think over here @OP is trying to limit the speed of those evil friends to less than 1Kbps, I have am also trying to search for any trick available to do that from a long time but I am still looking for answers on this one !

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But it will restrict the data and his friend will not able to use Internet after that limit. And he will not have any clue why internet is not working.

Comment: but the problem here is if I am also using the my data plan over the device then I'll also gets cuts down, I don't know if santosh is upto this one but according to me what will happen with me is my friend will ask me to look what has happened and I'll get caught, and I don't think this would be a good idea because my evil friend already have the idea that this person has an unlimited data plan.

Comment: @Peter have you checked edited answer.If you have a root access Please let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: Well @Ash-Ishh I haven't rooted my device and doesn't have plan to root it atleast this month, so I don't think I can confirm this maybe some one else over here could do that for me any what I can do is I'll remove my down vote because this time things looks as it's going to work any may be OP of this question can throw light on this one ! :)

Comment: @Peter I am also trying to find solution to controll it on non-rooted devices. If I will succeed I will update answer :) Because I am also having non-rooted device and dont want to root it now.

Comment: That's great, would be looking forward for your replies in future about it ! :)

Comment: Hey @Peter Just check out update. I dont know whether this option is available in all android versions (I tested on Jelly Bean 4.1.1) If it is available in your device let me know how much speed decreased in your case with this.

Comment: Well, which update you are talking about didn't see that... ??

Comment: Its working in Jelly Bean 4.1;
I also found one post about ' Mobile Data service preferred' here> http://www.mymobnet.com/make-android-device-browse-fasterboost-data-download-speed/

Comment: Hey @Ash-Ishh.. don't think you are going a little off topic over here ?? The post you have pointed to me has nothing to do with the question above!

Comment: Sorry mate! It was not my intention to make it more complex I just wanted to point out that option I mentioned in answer is available in android through link.But now I have realized It is really going off topic. Once again I apologize.